# Azure DevOps variables escape quotes

Tags: variables, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I got 2 variables in Azure DevOps Variable Group library:
variable1 = data"firstsomething" data"secondsomething"
variable2 = {"connectionstring":"$(variable1)"}

How to pass variable1 into variable2 to have value with quotes for connectionstring parameter? I need it to pass to ARM template as 1 of array parameter values.

Comment: Does the answer below resolved your question? If yes, you could accept it as answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another single quote if the value of your variable has double quotes. For example:
Here is my variable group:[image]
The result of `- script: echo $(variable2)` is:[image]

Comment: in that case when we pass variable1 to ARM template as -arrayvariable [$(variable1)] it will return error: Template parameter JToken type is not valid. Expected 'Array'. Actual 'String'.
So this transform array variable to string